# XGBoost error: feature names are different

Tags: r, xgboost

XGBoost gives this error:

```
Error in predict.xgb.Booster(m, newdata = data.matrix(.newdata), ...) : 
Feature names stored in `object` and `newdata` are different!
```

But, all these checks I run show no issues:

```
dim(df1)[2] == dim(df2)[2]
names(df1) == names(df2)
names(df1) %in% names(df2)
names(df1) %in% names(df2)

df1Types = sapply(df1, class)
df2Types = sapply(df2, class)
df1Types == df2Types
```

Ideas?

Comment: Please give reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

The factor levels must be the same in both data frames. In addition, the order of the factors must be the same as well.

-This may become a problem if you sort the order of the factors by their frequency in a data load function because the two data frames loaded with the same function may have factors with different orders.  The data may also have different factors depending on the data itself.